# PHP Adodb many sleeping connections

Tags: mysql, php, time-wait

Already asked the question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459313/php-adodb-many-sleeping-connections) but i guess this might be a better place for it.

I'm currently struggeling with a strange problem:
while using adodb as connection layer for php, it leaves many sleeping and unneeded connections behind. `wait_timeout` is set to `20` but there are still plenty (~100) of sleeping connections due to high load on the system. MySQL Version: `5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`

Is there a known bug regarding adodb5 and sleeping connections? I'm *not* using persistent connections! Connection establishment:

```
$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->Connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME)
```

Would really appreciate any hints/suggestions how to reduce sleeping connection count.

Machine Setup: two servers with `apache2` and `lighty`, loadbalancer and firewall in front, `nfs mount` with document root and virtual machine with `mysql`.

Got a huge amount of connections to the database:

```
863 <db01>
```

other machine:

```
476 <db01>
```

Strange thing: there are only 3-6 active processes on the database - the other ones are sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay finally found the problem: vhost document root was on an nfs mount (remote). this mount had some IO issues which provoked apache to "idle" connections until the nfs mount is ready again.